# Microsoft Shim throws Ambiguous match exception when encounters methods with the same name in a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to fake/mock db access for my unit tests.I chose Microsoft Fakes to accomplish that job.My main class has some same functions with different signatures like below.

```
public string GetValue(string key)
public T GetValue<T>(string key)
```

I added a fake assembly.It works fine with other methods(which has unique names in the class)however,when I try to fake/mock GetValue method I receive following error.

```
 using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
   Fakes.ShimFrmParamsBiz<FakeDbContext>.AllInstances.GetValueString = (x, y) => { return "Test"; };
}
```

**Ambiguous match exception**

Because It is legacy code,it is not possible to change method name right now.Any idea ?
Thanks advance

Comment: Hi. Not exactly sure what your problem is. But I tried Fakes long ago and also had issues. I would recommend giving moq4 a try. It's really popular and friendly

Comment: It seems fake assembly get confused when a class has methods with the same name.Like I mentioned in the question, It couldn't make the right choice between below methods.So It throws ambiguous reference error.I think I will go for moq.

public string GetValue(string key)
public T GetValue<T>(string key)